# Is there a Python implementation of Welch-Satterthwaite MANOVA?

Tags: python, statistics, manova

I have looked around in the [Python Package Index](https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=search&term=Welch-Satterthwaite%20MANOVA&submit=search), [Github](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=Welch-Satterthwaite%20MANOVA), and [Sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/directory/os:linux/?q=Welch-Satterthwaite%20MANOVA), but I have yet to find a Python implementation of [MANOVA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_analysis_of_variance) with degrees of freedom calculated with the [Welch-Satterthwaite Equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welch%E2%80%93Satterthwaite_equation). Has someone found an implementation for this? Maybe by another name?